# Рассчитать общую сумму (либо среднее число - average) для каждого повторяющихся дня, в выбранном периоде дат, для показа графика

Tags: c#, алгоритм, дата, график, логика

веб приложение на блазор

Если пользователь выбирает промежуток (например) три недели на календаре, как ему показать общее/среднее число каждого понедельника, вторника итд. на графике ?

Я использую дату для показа дней (XName), чтоб решить данную задачу я решила использовать день недели, мой график просто показывает на одной оси все числа.

```
public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }
private DayOfWeek dayOfWeekValue { get; set; }
public DayOfWeek DayOfWeekValue { get => DateValue.DayOfWeek; set { dayOfWeekValue = value; } }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может группировку я могу изменить?

```
private async Task GetCalendar2()
{
    if (weighsModels != null)
    {
        chart1 = weighsModels.Where(d => d.date >= MinDate && d.date <= MaxDate).ToList();

        var groupTotalByDay = from chart in chart1

                                group chart by chart.DateValue into ChartData
                                select new ModelChart()
                                    {
                                        DateValue = ChartData.Key,
                                        YNameValue = ChartData.Sum(x => x.YNameValue),
                                    };
        chart1 = groupTotalByDay.ToList();
    }
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

сейчас график базируется на двух календарях, первый показывает "текущую неделю" выбранной даты, а второй календарь позволяет выбрать "промежуток". так вот я показываю все дни, что выбрал пользователей, а мне нужно "суммировать" "повторяющиеся" дни
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ОЖИДАНИЯ:
то есть график ВСЕГДА показывает неделю, меняются, просто данные (прибавляет YNameValue каждого одинакового дня недели) *(я не понимаю зачем такое делать (все дни показать куда полезней), но это запрос клиента...)*

[на github выложила пример](https://github.com/Dev18000/ExampleForAvrDayChart/blob/master/ExampleForAvrDayChart/Pages/Index.razor)

upd: как то можно вызвать к дням функцию sum, при условии, что даты разные ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что такое "среднее число каждого понедельника" ?

Comment: @4per исправила

Comment: @4per чтоб наглядно, например на понедельник 23 и 9 две линии проходят. Так вот надо, чтоб одна линия с суммой 32 была

Answer (score 1, accepted):

расчитать среднее число в [таблице онлайн](https://allcalc.ru/node/1830)
[пуш гихаб update](https://github.com/Dev18000/ExampleForAvrDayChart/blob/master/ExampleForAvrDayChart/Pages/Index.razor)

решение предложила служба `syncfusion`, `ConvertDateTime` позволила расправить график, и решить вопрос с графиком, который показывал все данные на вертикальной линии. Размещаю в виде ответа, сейчас если выбрать промежуток две недели, график считает общую сумму двух понедельников, осталось только найти Average-среднее число. Сейчас когда я применяю average вместо sum, то получаю не верные данные, тк. average расчитывает деля на количество данных, а надо делить на дни, чтоб получить то самое среднее число (переводчик переводит Average как среднее число, прошу поправить , тк в комментариях был вопрос, может не так перевела‍♀️)

для примера выбираю промежуток 16-24 попадает два понедельника
на 16+23 два понедельника у нас 32 (23+9) общее число

```
new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,16), YNameValue = 10, }, 
        new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,16), YNameValue = 5, },
        new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,16), YNameValue = 5, },
        new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,16), YNameValue = 3, }, //23
new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,23), YNameValue = 1, },
        new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,23), YNameValue = 1, },
        new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,23), YNameValue = 3, },
        new ModelChart{ date = new DateTime(2022,05,23), YNameValue = 4, }, //9
```

понедельник (lundi) равен 32
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private async Task GetCalendar2()
{
    if (weighsModels != null)
    {
        chart1 = weighsModels.Where(d => d.date >= MinDate && d.date <= MaxDate).ToList();

        var groupTotalByDay = from chart in chart1

        group chart by chart.date.DayOfWeek into ChartData
        select new ModelChart()
        {
            date = ConvertDateTime(ChartData.Key),   
            YNameValue = ChartData.Sum(x => x.YNameValue),
            // смотришь и думаешь, я же вроде так пробовала
            // а это для average
            //YNameValue = ChartData.Sum(x => x.YNameValue)/ChartData.GroupBy(chart => chart.date).Count(),
         };
         chart1 = groupTotalByDay.ToList();
     }
     this.StateHasChanged();
}

private DateTime ConvertDateTime(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    int diff = dayOfWeek - date.DayOfWeek;
    if (diff < 0)
    {
        diff += 7;
    }
    return date.AddDays(diff);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>  group chart by chart.DateValue into ChartData
> ```

```
 group chart by chart.DateValue.DayOfWeek into ChartData
```

Comment: я много раз перечитала ваш ответ, пыталась вникнуть в вашу логику, думаю может не вижу скрытую подсказку...                  вы читали вопрос ? я же там говорю, что так и сделала , группировала по дням (dayOfWeek) и первый скрин шот показывает, что если я группирую таким образом, то все падает на одну линию по горизонтали //если вы скачаете проект его можно запустить, может так вам наглядней будет как там все устроенно, и вы сможете помочь ?